# ORA-06550 exception while calling oracle stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to call an oracle stored procedure from my C# application and I get the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'DELETE_SEARCH'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

The procedure declaration is:

```
PROCEDURE delete_search (user_ip IN VARCHAR2)
```

and th C# code that suppose to call it is:

```
OracleCommand cmd;
OracleParameter param;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (decimal.Parse(data.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString()) < numericUpDown1.Value)
    {
        cmd = new OracleCommand("delete_search", Form1.conn());
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        param = new OracleParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "ip";
        param.Value = data.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        Form1.adapter().SelectCommand = cmd;
        Form1.adapter().SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and of course the exception is thrown in the line:

```
Form1.adapter().SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

shouldn't

```
param.ParameterName = "ip";
```

be

```
param.ParameterName = "user_ip";
```

Comment: You are probably correct here. However note that `OracleCommand` by default binds by parameter order and ignores the name, unless BindByName is set to true.  However I don't know if that is just for queries or applies to stored procedures too:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/OracleCommandClass.htm#i997666

Comment: from [the .NET docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.71).aspx#Y122) - **Using Parameters with a SqlCommand** - When using parameters with a SqlCommand, the names of the parameters added to the Parameters collection must match the names of the parameter markers in your stored procedure. The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server treats parameters in the stored procedure as named parameters and searches for the matching parameter markers.

Comment: good to know. I knew `BindByName` took effect for regular queries, but wasn't sure about stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong param name. It should be

```
param.ParameterName = "user_ip";
```